# What to do with excess fat in meat?

Tags: pork, fat

Recently I was preparing kotlet schabowy from pork tenderloin. The tenderloin had a bit of excess fat in it and I cut it out(a small slice, approx 3-5mm x 1cm x 5cm).

What can I do with those? I don't really like throwing things away and it looks like it could be useful. I cut it into small pieces and roasted it in a pan to get a nice brown color on it and it gave off a bit of that fat into the pan. Looked nice too, but was chewy(well, it's a fat), so definitely not something I would try to eat.

Do I have to toss it away, or is there any way to make that edible?

Comment: I'm voting close this as questions of the form "What can I do with [ingredient]?" are off-topic because they are subjective and lead to a long list of equally good suggestions, which is not compatible with the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: @GdD is there a way I could ask this question, rephrase it or change a bit so that it belongs on this site?

Comment: Frankly no @MatthewRock, not unless you fundamentally change the substance of the question.

Comment: @GdD : the line used to be drawn so that what would otherwise be trash was allowed.  But the faq now includes "Ingredient selection and use" and this is an ingredient use.

Comment: If we close this one then we have to go back and close https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56186/what-can-i-do-with-the-meat-and-fat-trimmed-from-the-top-of-lamb-ribs?rq=1 and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/38167/what-can-i-do-with-the-fat-skimmed-from-chicken-stock?rq=1 I think this is a useful question.

Answer (score 6):

What you describe is known as 'rendering' the fat -- you cook it until the liquid comes off.  But the goal isn't to eat the fat, but to create something oily that you can cook with.

If I'm just rendering for later, I'll strain the fat before putting it into a container to keep in my fridge.  If I'm going to be immediately cooking with it, I'll chop it up first (it helps to put it in the freezer for 10 to 30 minutes so it'll firm up before cutting).  Chopping it up also gives it more surface area so it renders faster.

But it's important to note -- there are a few things that get trimmed from meat besides fat:

- tendons : ribbons, usually bright white; used to connect muscles to bones.  They need to be removed, as they're always tough and chewy.
- silverskin : slightly greyish shiny film; Also needs to be removed, as it's like chewing rubber when cooked.

If either of those two are in there, you'll want to discard the fat bits after they've been rendered.

In other situations, you can cook the fat bits until they're browned, remove them with a slotted spoon, and let drain on a paper towel.  You'll end up with crunchy bits that you can add back into the dish later (like the fatty part of bacon)

...

Some other uses (besides feeding to birds) :

- Throw it in when making a pork stock.  The fat will help to cap the stock when you store it in the fridge.
- Save it to grind up when making sausage.  (if you make sausage)

Comment: I save all extra fat either rendered or in chunks. Occasionally, the chunks are a great snack fried up with some spice rub (think cracklins), though they can be pretty rich.

Answer (score 2):

While you can render it and use it for frying, it's probably not worth it for such a small quantity.

Personally I'd chop it finely and feed it to the birds in my garden.

Comment: With larger amounts, you can make a suet feeder

Comment: @Joe, yes. I don't get through enough meat for that any more but used to make them (especially around Christmas - more fat from joints, leftover suet from baking, and more customers)